# VBnet check if a value found is a part of a table in Word

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

I have wrote a script to search for and return specific values found in a Word file. Ex. The script is looking for all values in a Word document (with Interop.Word) with the paratemeters of "([)(*)(])". This works fine.

My issue is to identify if each value found is a part of a table in the Word file. The purpose is to delete the specific row where the value is found if the value exist in a table in Word.

Is it possible to check if a value found is a part of a table in Word?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over tables, converting them to text and search for your text.

Considering that *doc* is the `Word.Document` you are automating.

```
For each wtable as Word.Table in doc.Tables

Dim str as string

Str = wtable.ConvertToText(Separator:=vbTab, _
    NestedTables:=False).Text

If str.Contains("search text")
    Msgbox("found")
End if

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problems converting this VBA code to VB.NET:

```
Sub FindInTables()
    Dim oDocument As Document
    Dim oRange As range

    Set oDocument = Application.ActiveDocument
    Set oRange = oDocument.range

    With oRange.find
        Do While .Execute(FindText:="bla", Forward:=True, MatchWildcards:=True)

            If oRange.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                oRange.Rows.Delete
            End If

            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Basically, you use the find object on the range that you want to search through, and then you check the amount of tables in the range that is found to determine if it's in a table. If so you call .Delete on the .Rows collection of the found range.